# removing title bar of emacs in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, emacs, title-bar

I'd like to remove the title bar of emacs in Windows XP. E.g., f11 in Internet Explorer or Firefox.

I haven't run across any result in `apropos` that suggests this is possible in emacs itself. I've not run across a practical solution (like a registry hack) to enable this.

Answer (score 0):

does "M-x menu-bar-mode" do what you want?

If so, the bar you want hidden is called "menu bar". The title bar is the one with the window's title and min/max/close buttons.

Comment: Yes, I want the title bar gone. Not the menu bar.

Answer (score 0):

A bit left field, but you could use AutoHotkey to send window messages to emacs that would position and resize it emacs' window to look like it was full screen, plus be on top of every window, and then bind it to f11 or some keystroke in emacs. As a bonus you could probably make the script work for any window, not just emacs.

Check out some of the examples here: http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic29129.html and here http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=51664